# What is the correct translation of "Do we go to the cinema?"

Tags: anglais

Nous allons à le cinéma!

Means "We go to the cinema". But how would I say you want to include the word "do", like a question

Do we go to the cinema?

Can I just add the word "faire" that means "do"?

Faire nous allons à le cinéma?

What is correct?

Comment: “Do” is not a verb here, it's an auxiliary. It doesn't have the meaning of the verb (act, make) here. As an auxiliary, “do” doesn't really carry any meaning, it's just here because English grammar requires an auxiliary in a direct question except when the verb is *be*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We go to the cinema.

formally translates to:

> *Nous allons **au** cinéma* (note that ***à le*** turns to ***au***).

but the usual way to say it would use ***on*** instead of ***nous***:

> *On va au cinéma*.

When a question, French doesn't use "do" but either inversion, specific adverbs or just intonation so that makes:

> *Allons-nous au cinéma ?* (formal, literary)
>
> *Est-ce que nous allons au cinéma ?* (formal)
>
> *Est-ce qu'on va au cinéma ?* (standard)

Here are common, real life variants:

> *On va au ciné ?*
>
> *On se fait une toile ?*

Comment: So I can use this `Allons-nous au cinéma ?` ?

Comment: Sure, that would delight a French language teacher.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: ** *Varsågod* **